# Why is my NGINX downloading files?

Tags: php, nginx

I've set up a redirect so I can serve my PHP files without the `.php` extension, but whenever I visit a "clean" url, my browser downloads the file, suggesting NGINX isn't hosting it as a PHP file.

How can I fix this issue (and security hole)?

The config:

```
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  www.example.com;
    root         /var/www/html/public;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ @extensionless-php;
        index index.html index.htm index.php;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri =404;
        include       /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_pass  unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    }

    location @extensionless-php {
        rewrite ^(.*)$ $1.php last;
    }
}
```

Comment: How did you setup PHP5 FPM?

Comment: @muru: Default settings, nothing special.

Comment: Try adding `fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;` below `fastcgi_pass`. (based on http://serverfault.com/a/558041/229499 and http://www.tweaktalk.net/60/nginx-remove-php-file-extension-from-url

Comment: @muru Nope. Still not working.

Comment: Same problem here.

Comment: have you tried adding this to your nginx.conf file ? 

`include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;`

Comment: @AliRezaMosajjal Already there.

Comment: Extensionless PHP doesn't appear to be doing its rewrites properly.  I would hazard a guess and say that it's that rewrite, or PHP, not working properly

Answer (score 0):

Using the Chrome Inspector Network tab, review the raw HTTP response headers set for this configuration vs a working PHP page. You will see the `Content-Type` is different between the pages. It is the alternative `Content-Type` that causes the browser to [respond by downloading the file rather than displaying it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2966199/apache-giving-pages-as-downloads-rather-than-displaying-them).

In your `@extensionless-php` block, try adding this to force the `Content-Type` back to a standard HTML MIME type:

```
 default_type text/html;
```